# axios POST method seems to be 'transformed' to OPTIONS method on the fly

Tags: json, rest, vue.js, http, axios

I use this sample code:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    url: 'http://somePlace:8040/someWSendpoint',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
});
```

But that request never reach its destination. Apparently, because the **POST method is transformed to OPTIONS method**, and rejected by the endpoint url.

This is what the 'Network' window shows in the Chrome inspector:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS

Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

This is what the 'Console' window shows in the Chrome inspector:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://somePlace:8040/someWSendpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js?b50d:160 POST http://somePlace:8040/someWSendpoint net::ERR_FAILED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:160
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:11
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:51
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
send_firma @ AltaFirma.vue?c240:504
click @ AltaFirma.vue?3ed8:1812
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:69)
```

I am wondering if people "at the other side" need to configure something related to that CORS thing in his server ¿?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: This is a CORS issue. You need to include CORS headers in the response (from the server-side). The browser error already tells you that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing, so add it from the server-side. Please include your server code, or let us know a bit more about the stack (Express?) to write a proper answer.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests